# Is it possible to create a complex platformer game with SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, game-engine

[image: A platformer game]

Can we achieve this with SKPhsyicsBody? I already did some research, and knew SpriteKit physics body does handle irregular shapes like curves. But there's no mentioning that the SKNote's rotation angle will dynamically change like the example game provided (made with unity) in the image. It would be a really bad experience for players when the main element of the game does not follow the curve with its rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, yes you can. And yes, yes it will (rotate with contact). All possible, all permitted and all exactly how the physics bodies interact. This is simply a matter of setting friction properties between the surface (ground) and your hero's ski in conjunction with gravity so it provides your idealised experience.